# Signin Soap request and unrecognized path attribute

Tags: asp.net, soap, x509

I am using [Web Services Enhancements 1.0 for Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996951.aspx) to sign my Soap request. With wireshark I can see the Soap request, which looks to be signed.

I have written a test server with well-known `HelloWorld()` method. But an error occured, saying that "path" attribute is not recognized.

This in an extract of the Soap request, in `<soap:Header>` section:

```
<wsrp:path soap:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsrp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/rp">
<wsrp:action wsu:Id="Id-177d0898-4b52-4807-8042-34c2107414ee" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld</wsrp:action>
<wsrp:to wsu:Id="Id-bd6f000f-c2e9-40c4-8ae5-7316dcb08295" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">http://xxxx/yyyy.asmx</wsrp:to>
<wsrp:id wsu:Id="Id-9ceacb6a-d758-4ab5-9e4a-2c25b77005f7" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">uuid:e4e7eda7-b4a3-4661-91c6-42ee17fb6b61</wsrp:id>
</wsrp:path>
```

It [looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977349.aspx) that "path" attribute it used to relay the request (??). But why the server don't understand this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MWSE assembly has to be declared in server too (web.config).